# AnimatedSwitcher not working in ReorderableListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm trying to get AnimatedSwitcher to work in a ReorderableListView, it works in a normal ListView. I'm thinking it has something to do with the keys, but I'm now sure.

Flutter 1.17.0 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision e6b34c2b5c (7 days ago) • 2020-05-02 11:39:18 -0700
Engine • revision 540786dd51
Tools • Dart 2.8.1

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => ChangeNumber(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Consumer<ChangeNumber>(
              builder: (context, value, child) {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 100,
                      child: ReorderableListView(
                        onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {},
                        children: <Widget>[
                          AnimatedSwitcher(
                            key: ValueKey(value.i),
                            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                            child: NumberTile(
                              number: value.i,
                              key: ValueKey(value.i),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      child: Text('Increase'),
                      onPressed: () => value.i = value.i + 1,
                    )
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NumberTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final int number;

  NumberTile({this.number, key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('$number'),
    );
  }
}

class ChangeNumber extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _i = 0;

  get i => _i;

  set i(int value) {
    _i = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're just updating a number, not switching out a widget for another widget. I don't believe the animated switcher will work unless you replace the child of the `AnimatedSwitcher` with a new child. Altering your `ReorderableListView` to a `ListView` doesn't seem to work from your code example above.

Comment: If you change ReorderedListView with a ListView and remove the key on the AnimatedSwitcher it will work.
child: ListView(
children: <Widget>[
                          AnimatedSwitcher(
                            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                            child: NumberTile(
                              number: value.i,
                              key: ValueKey(value.i),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),

Answer (score 0):

`AnimatedSwitcher` will not show effect on `Text` widget as your `Text` is inside `ListTile` inside `NumberTile`. You have to place the direct widget which you want to animate the switch inside the `AnimatedSwitcher`. Check this [example](https://medium.com/flutter-community/what-do-you-know-about-aniamtedswitcher-53cc3a4bebb8)

Comment: It will in fact: https://dartpad.dev/5b06dfbd75acf1fe3ff16415a6956987

Comment: It is just because you are applying Key to NumberTile with ValueKey of increament. That means the NumberTile  with ValueKey(0) is different from  NumberTile  with ValueKey(1). So AnimatedSwitcher thnks thats a different child.

Comment: How can I implement this, using a ReorderableListView instead of ListView?

Comment: Place the Text inside the AnimatedSwitcher directly

Comment: That is not the point, the example is just to illustrate the issue. And that will still not work.